# Inconsistent TOUCHSTART event in Android 4.0 "Ice Cream Sandwich"

Tags: javascript, android, button, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, touchstart

I've noticed that `BUTTON` elements receive `TOUCHSTART` events very inconsistently in Android 4.0. I added event listeners on a particular `BUTTON` for the `TOUCHSTART`, `MOUSEDOWN` and `CLICK` events and on all of our Ice Cream Sandwich test devices the `TOUCHSTART` event fires infrequently and inconsistently whereas the `MOUSEDOWN` and `CLICK` events fire every time.

Normally I would just rely on the other two events and be done with it, but the lead on the particular project I'm working on right now is pretty adamant about using the `TOUCHSTART` event on mobile devices.

Any thoughts on how I can get around this issue with Android?

Comment: did you find any solution to this problem?